# java inline Streams and Optional<T> at compile time

Tags: java, optimization, build, java-8

I absolutely love the Java 8 features, because of readability, but I am concerned about performance degrading that they might cause. While it probably doesn't affect the application speed in the long run due to JIT, it might affect memory usage, which is one of my primary concerns. IntelliJ IDEA provides the option to convert Stream API usages to loops (for single usage). **Is there a way to inline all these features every time I build my project?**

For example, if I use `find("my-record").ifPresent(records::add)`, I would expect these changes: signature of `Optional<Record> find(String)` to be converted to (Nullable) `Record find(String)` and the method call to be converted to a null-check.

Note: I know that there are tons of subtle differences between, say, streams and loops, but I design my code not to rely on details of implementation.

Comment: "probably [...] it might affect memory usage" do you have any indication that this really applies (in a significant way) to you concrete situation?

Comment: Streams tend to create quite a few objects, loops and 'if' create none, right? Besides, there are several benchmarks (which seem believable) where small-sized streams can be >5 times slower.

Comment: That would mean this feature would adjust both the return type of the called method from `Optional<Record>` to `Record` and all calls to it. That's a questionable approach since it relies on all dependencies of the callee to be built using that feature.

Comment: I see... if such feature would be possible, about how much time would it add to the building process? I don't see any similar issues with Streams though.

Comment: Do you actually have a performance problem? Looks like a case of premature optimization.

Comment: It might be premature, but I've noticed in my past projects that memory usage and GC pauses are the two limitations (one causing the other) which force me to rent better hardware.

Comment: I would worry about what that `find` method actually does rather than how it returns the result. You’re surely looking at the wrong end.

Comment: This is not actual code

Comment: There are several similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24923040, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096361, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7772864, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35601841, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228141

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in all the similar questions I linked to from my comment, the Java8 SDK itself does not offer ways to add such optimizations during compile time.

The Java 9 "Ahead-of-time" compiler may [inline more aggressively](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/goals-reqs/03#enable-ahead-of-time-whole-program-optimization-techniques).

> The optimization techniques envisioned here include, but are not
>   limited to: Fast lookup of both JDK and application classes; early
>   bytecode verification; aggressive inlining of, e.g., lambda
>   expressions, and other standard compiler optimizations; [...]

Also [ProGuard](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/introduction) does some inlining:

> In the optimization step, ProGuard further optimizes the code. Among
>   other optimizations, classes and methods that are not entry points can
>   be made private, static, or final, unused parameters can be removed,
>   and some methods may be inlined.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I was more interested in _object inlining_ as opposed to simple function inlining. But the AOT definitely looks promising, at least for some cases (I'm aware of it's shortsomings). And thanks for ProGuard - never used it before, but seems like a useful tool.